# ASP how to find controls of type on a child page of a master page

Tags: c#, panel

I have a master page master.page.

And I have a child page default.aspx that inheirts master.

How do I preform the following and actually find controls.  In the below code I never find my panels.

codebehind - content-page

```
foreach (Panel pnl in this.Page.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
    if (pnl.ID.ToUpper() == texthi.ToUpper().Replace(" ", ""))
    {
        pnl.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pnl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

aspx - content-page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/secure/Wizard.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="AddWarranty.aspx.cs" Inherits="secure_Warranties_AddWarranty" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_NavigationPanel"
    runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="header">
        <p id="layoutdims">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="colmask leftmenu">
        <div class="colleft">
            <div class="col1">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="VehicleInformation" Visible="true">
                    <legend>VEHICLE INFORMATION</legend>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CustomerInformation" Visible="false">
                    <legend>CUSTOMER INFORMATION</legend>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code located? If it's located in the master, why does your master control it's content-pages at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I dont follow sorry

Comment: @TimSchmelter its on default.aspx on Page_Load()

Comment: are the controls you're looking for in the master page?

Comment: If it's in your content-page and the panels are in your content-page, how is this question related to the master at all? If the panels are in the master, provide a property in the master that returns them. The page has a `Master` property which you need to cast to the correct type before you can use that property.

Comment: Well then I guess the question is why with 3 panels does this.Page.Control.OfType find 0 panels?  It has to be related to the master/child page

Comment: @Mike: show your aspx page, where are these panels? Are they created dynamically or are they nested in child-containers like a `Repeater`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter   I added it just not sure how let SO show the html

Comment: @mike: note that i've edited my answer, the container control of the panels is not the page but the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `Enumerable.TypeOf` does not look recursivelsy into child controls but only the top-container. Since you're using it on the page's `ControlCollection` you'll find only panels which are sitting on the top of the page. But your panels are inside of other divs.

Make   the parent `div`(with `class="col1"`) `runat=server`(or use `Panel`) and access it in codebehind:

```
foreach (Panel pnl in div.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{  
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tim - made col1 runat="server" but i cant find the div in intellisense in code behind

Comment: @Mike: what `ID` have you assigned? Remember to stop execution before you edit the aspx-file, otherwise it's not created automatically in codebehind. But i would use a servercontrol anyway if i need to access it in codebehind, so in this case a `Panel` which is rendered as a `div`.

Comment: Hah, i pulled a newbie move, i made it runat="server" with no id :(